# Use String list as source of Combo Box

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I wanted to use a String list as a source of various options in jComboBox in Java. Can you tell which method to use

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

See Below for my answer... take into account this is untested and merely an example.

You need to create a custom implmentation of ComboBoxModel like Chandru said,
Then set the ComboBoxModel on your JComboBox using the `setModel()` method and add elements using `((CustomComboBoxModel<String>)jComboBox.getModel()).add(listOfThings);`
Something like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;

/**
 * Custom Implementation of {@code ComboBoxModel} to allow adding a list of
 * elements to the list.
 */
public interface CustomComboBoxModel<T> extends ComboBoxModel {

    void add(List<T> elementsToAdd);

    List<T> getElements();

}
```

and then implement the interface using something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;

/**
 * Default Implementation of CustomComboBoxModel - untested.
 */
public class DefaultCustomComboBoxModel<T> extends AbstractListModel implements CustomComboBoxModel<T> {

    List<T> objects;
    T selectedObject;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty DefaultCustomComboBoxModel object.
     */
    public DefaultCustomComboBoxModel() {
        objects = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a DefaultCustomComboBoxModel object initialized with
     * an array of objects.
     *
     * @param items  an array of Object objects
     */
    public DefaultCustomComboBoxModel(final T items[]) {
        objects = new ArrayList<T>();

        int i, c;
        for (i = 0, c = items.length; i < c; i++) {
            objects.add(items[i]);
        }

        if (getSize() > 0) {
            selectedObject = objects.get(0);
        }
    }

    // implements javax.swing.ComboBoxModel
    /**
     * Set the value of the selected item. The selected item may be null.
     * Make sure {@code anObject} is an instance of T otherwise a
     * ClassCastException will be thrown.
     * <p>
     * @param anObject The combo box value or null for no selection.
     */
    @Override
    public void setSelectedItem(Object anObject) {
        if ((selectedObject != null && !selectedObject.equals(anObject))
                || selectedObject == null && anObject != null) {
            selectedObject = (T) anObject;
            fireContentsChanged(this, -1, -1);
        }
    }

    // implements javax.swing.ComboBoxModel
    @Override
    public T getSelectedItem() {
        return selectedObject;
    }

    // implements javax.swing.ListModel
    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    // implements javax.swing.ListModel
    @Override
    public T getElementAt(int index) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < objects.size()) {
            return objects.get(index);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the index-position of the specified object in the list.
     *
     * @param anObject
     * @return an int representing the index position, where 0 is
     *         the first position
     */
    public int getIndexOf(T anObject) {
        return objects.indexOf(anObject);
    }

    // implements javax.swing.MutableComboBoxModel
    public void addElement(T anObject) {
        objects.add(anObject);
        fireIntervalAdded(this, objects.size() - 1, objects.size() - 1);
        if (objects.size() == 1 && selectedObject == null && anObject != null) {
            setSelectedItem(anObject);
        }
    }

    // implements javax.swing.MutableComboBoxModel
    public void insertElementAt(T anObject, int index) {
        objects.add(index, anObject);
        fireIntervalAdded(this, index, index);
    }

    // implements javax.swing.MutableComboBoxModel
    public void removeElementAt(int index) {
        if (getElementAt(index) == selectedObject) {
            if (index == 0) {
                setSelectedItem(getSize() == 1 ? null : getElementAt(index + 1));
            } else {
                setSelectedItem(getElementAt(index - 1));
            }
        }

        objects.remove(index);

        fireIntervalRemoved(this, index, index);
    }

    // implements javax.swing.MutableComboBoxModel
    public void removeElement(T anObject) {
        int index = objects.indexOf(anObject);
        if (index != -1) {
            removeElementAt(index);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Empties the list.
     */
    public void removeAllElements() {
        if (objects.size() > 0) {
            int firstIndex = 0;
            int lastIndex = objects.size() - 1;
            objects.clear();
            selectedObject = null;
            fireIntervalRemoved(this, firstIndex, lastIndex);
        } else {
            selectedObject = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(List<T> elementsToAdd) {
        objects.addAll(elementsToAdd);
        fireContentsChanged(this, -1, -1);

    }

    @Override
    public List<T> getElements() {
        return objects;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no commentary here, three upvotes and the answerer said *"take into account this is untested and merely an example"*...does this work?

Comment: @pureferret I forgot about this one, I'll have a go and put together a test case using this code and get back to you...

Comment: I've just implemented it, the only beef it seems to have with an 'untyped cast to T' or 'to type Object', I think. I can't find it now as I've suppressed it.

Comment: @pureferret, no problem then, it was merely an example how to implement it. let me know if you need any more help

Answer (score 3):

Extend [DefaultComboboxModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) and create a method which takes a Collection and sets the items from that collection.  Set this custom model as your combobox's model using `setModel()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have code which creates combo box from array of Strings, all you need to do is transform your list to an array. 
    String petStrings = ...;

```
//Create the combo box, select item at index 4.
//Indices start at 0, so 4 specifies the pig.
JComboBox petList = new JComboBox(petStrings.toArray());
```

Comment: i want to create the Combo box list on the fly based on some other user selection. Hence i need to set it to the combo box as i cannot initialize in the constructor. Hence i was looking at some method to either set a list or an array to the box

Comment: So I think you can use DefaultComboBoxModel class, it provides convinient way for adding and removing element as well as getting selected element. Then set this model to JComboBox via setModel method.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

```
comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(list.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post, but I wanted to make a small addition to edwardsmatt's DefaultCustomComboBoxModel. Don't forget to add this constructor:

```
public DefaultCustomComboBoxModel(List<T> list) {
    objects = list;

    if (getSize() > 0) {
        selectedObject = objects.get(0);
    }
}
```

so that the model can also be initialized with a list, e.g.

```
myCombo.setModel(new DefaultCustomComboBoxModel(myList));
```

If you use `((CustomComboBoxModel)myCombo.getModel()).add(myList)` you'll need to explicitly set the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
 DefaultTableModel modelTabele = (DefaultTableModel) tblOsobe.getModel();
    modelTabele.addColumn("Ime");
    modelTabele.addColumn("Prezime");
    modelTabele.addColumn("Datum Rodjenja");

    for (Osoba osoba : Liste.osobe) {
        System.out.println("" + osoba);
        Object[] podaci = new Object[3];
        podaci[0] = osoba.getIme();
        podaci[1] = osoba.getPrezime();
        podaci[2] = osoba.getDatumRodjenja();
        modelTabele.addRow(podaci);

    }
```

This model has 3 columns and as many rows as there are in Liste.osobe list of strings.