# Adding to a databse, and editable ComboBoxModel on 'enter' press...with a keylistener?

Tags: java, swing

I'd like to add to a database, and my editable comboBoxModel when I enter a new name into the comboBox. I have the method for adding to the database down fine, I'm just trying to get it to somehow listen to an entry being added to the ComboBox.

**What's the Best way to do this?**

I've read the Java tutorial on [Editable ComboBoxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#editable), and noted where it said:

> An editable combo box fires an action event when the user chooses an item from the menu and when the user types Enter. Note that the menu remains unchanged when the user enters a value into the combo box. If you want, *you can easily write an action listener that adds a new item to the combo box's menu each time the user types in a unique value*.

So I thought to myself, ok lets try this, and looked up some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6395164/1075247). Here is my attempt, essentially copy pasted out of the example I found, with my variable names:

```
playerNameComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("comboBoxEdited")) {
            System.out.println("Adding new player!");
            IController.Util.getInstance().addNewPlayer();
            playerNameComboBox.insertItemAt(playerNameComboBox.getSelectedItem(), 0);
        }
    }
});
```

When I type in a new name, and press enter, it does nothing. No new database entry and no addtional option on the ComboBox. I haven't attached an action command to the ComboBox as I thought the example above assumed it would have that as default, and so did I.

But how do I get it to shout out that action command when I press enter, with the focus on the comboBox? I would have thought that comboBoxes would have had some sort of default behaviour to shout that out? Do I need to use an `if(playerNameComboBox.hasFocus())` statement? Should I implement some kind of keylistener when my comboBox hasFocus()?

I'm very new at Java, so I'm unsure as to how this sort of thing should be done; any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Your listener and `actionPerformed()` look fine. Did you remember to call `playerNameComboBox.setEditable(true);`?

Comment: Yes, I did. See my soon-to-be edit.

Comment: I see. Do you also not get anything on the console when you press enter? I wrote a short test program with everything but the database call, and it's working fine. I could post it in an answer if you like.

Comment: @JosephKendall Nothing, I'd love to see an SSCCE in an answer though

Comment: Remember, action listeners are not fired on focus lost

Comment: @MadProgrammer what would cause a loss of focus? I'm pressing enter to try and 'fire' the action.

Comment: @Pureferret That's fine, I'm just making aware of the fact that if the user moves from the field, it may not trigger an Action Event

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, I'll bear that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is my short example in which names may be added to a JComboBox.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private JComboBox box;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test()
    {
        super();
        setSize(200, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        box = new JComboBox();
        box.setEditable(true);
        getContentPane().add(box);

        box.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                if (e.getActionCommand().equals("comboBoxEdited")) { 
                    System.out.println("Adding new player!");
                    box.insertItemAt(box.getSelectedItem(), 0);
                } 
            } 
        });

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks, exactly like my code, I'll have a look at work tomorrow and see if something else is not working tomorrow.

Comment: I just ran this at home, +1 it works. I'll see if this differs from my code tomorrow at work.

Comment: I've realised my mistake: I'm using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2305474/1075247), which meant I need to make some changes. It works now using this answer.

Comment: Ah, yeah. `this` would refer to the inner class itself, while `ClassName.this` (using whatever your class name really is, not literally "ClassName") could be used to still refer to the outer class. I've made that mistake before. Glad you've figured things out, though.